# How to determine a system is stable without knowing the input?

Tags: control-system, input, stability, system

I was doing some exercises for an upcoming exam and ran into this. I am not sure how to find if the system is stable without knowing the actual input (since Routh array is the only method I'm familiar with.) (The answer provided is a)

Can someone explain briefly what needs to be done?
Thank you in advance!

[image: Exercise]

Comment: This is probably better asked on [Engineering.SO](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/) since it doesn't deal with electronics.

Comment: okay, thank you sir, I am new to the community! have a nice day!

Comment: In EE we normally talk about "bounded-input bounded-output" (BIBO) stability. That means we say a system is stable if it is stable for any input that is bounded in amplitude. If that's what is meant by stability in your course, you shouldn't need to specify a particular input before deciding if the system is stable.

Comment: Thank you The Photon! I didn't know it should be all the same - even without specifying an input!

Comment: @RonBeyer Controls systems are a major area in EE, so even though the question is general in nature, it is well suited to be here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seemingly a homework.

Unstable system starts to generate increasing output if there exists some excitation other than a sometimes possible stabilizing one that is generated by external controller. Thus c is in the very beginning false. You must solve "a or b".

- Laplace transform the left and right side
- ignore the initial value terms
- replace the right side with 1 (it's all the same, what is the input)
- solve Y(s), you get a rational function of s
- solve the poles of Y(s) (= values of s that make the Y(s) indefinite due the division by zero)
- system is stable if all poles are in the left half of the complex s-plane

Imaginary poles are a limit case. The output continues to swing if some excitation has happened, but does not expand in amplitude. You must check, is it considered stability or unstability in your definitions.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering, it is really not a homework, it is a question from last years exam and I was stressing I wouldn't be able to solve it. I didn't know I had to replace the right side by 1. Thank you for being so extensive with your answer though, hope others who are having trouble can find it. (I wouldn't ask for homework here, I'm new to the community but I know it is not fair to do that)!